# Tkinter showerror appears again when return is bound

Tags: python, tkinter

I have used `root.bind("<Return>",enter)` which calls the function enter when the Return key (enter) is pressed. The function enter reads some input field and might call `tkMessageBox.showerror(header,text)` depending on the input. Pressing the return key will both press OK on the error and make the `tkMessageBox.showerror(header,text)` appear again, despite that the next line after `tkMessageBox.showerror(header,text)` is inputfield.delete(0,END).

This is the code:

```
enter():
    showerror("Error","Wrong input")
    streckkodEntry.delete(0,END)
```

This solves it:

```
enter():
    disable()
    showerror("Error","Wrong input")
    enable()
    streckkodEntry.delete(0,END)
```

where `disable()` removes the binding and `enable()` puts it back

This problem does only occur on my machine with Debian 7.0 but not my windows machine. Any ideas how to solve it without adding disable/enable for each showerror?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information for us to answer this question. Do you have traces on a variable associated with the entry? Do you have validation associated with the entry? Can you create a really small program that duplicates the problem?

Comment: If you are binding <return> to root, I am surprised that you do not have to disable the binding on Windows, but this is apparently one of the system-dependent peculiarities of how <return> is handled.  It may have something to do with not passing root to showerror.  Try binding <return> to the Entry widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! I had still defined the binding as `bind_all` rather than just `bind`. In windows this does not matter since the error message blocks the bind_all binding, only the error message can be interacted with. Debian 7.0 does not block the bind_all when a error message appears and the biding is working behind the error message as well.